# Displaying more than 10 recently used applications in Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 with Kickoff Application Launcher

Tags: kubuntu, kickoff

Is there any way to display more than 10 recently used applications in Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 with the ([Kickoff Application Launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff))?

Using the GUI settings I am limited to 10:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the answer for you. But the setting you are looking for **must** reside somewhere among the files in `~/.kde/share/config/` - there is simply no other way.